# Element not visible exception

Tags: c#, selenium

I am having trouble selecting an element as I keep getting the subject error.

Strangely it has worked once, and only once but then never since, using the exact same code.

R9_Automation.Logintest.Loginuser:
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : Element is not displayed

I have tried using, implicit and explict waits to no success, I have also tried clicking the element first as seen in the // code but this tells me the element cant be clicked as not visible.

My code is below:

```
            public static void Enterusername(string username)
    {

        //Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("txtUsername")).Click();
        Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("txtUsername")).SendKeys(username);
```

And the HTML is below:

```
      <form name="aspnetForm" id="aspnetForm" action="" method="post">
      <div id="container" style="top: 10px; margin-top: 249.56px; display: block;">
      <div class="login">
      <div class="figure">
      <div class="flex-content">
      <span class="siteStatusPlaceHolder">
      <p class="message"/>
      <fieldset class="user">
      <label for="txtUsername">
      <input name="ctl00$footerPlaceHolder$txtUsername" class="placeholder" id="txtUsername"         type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE="off" placeholder="username"/>
```

Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: Internet Explorer V10

Comment: Is your `<form>` inside an `<iframe>` ?

Comment: By the way your html seems wrong. There are no closing tags for `<span>` , `<label>` and `<p />` is not a valid html tag I think

Comment: It is not inside an IFrame